# Converter string em formato específico em data

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, conversão

Tenho uma *string* `"sex, nov 6"` e preciso converter para `DateTime`.

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
DateTime datetime =
DateTime.Parse(gridT.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString());
```

Porém, não está dando certo.

Como posso fazer essa conversão?

Comment: como vc carregar a data no gridT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você precisa fazer a [conversão exata](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_), mas se a data não estiver no formato esperado, lascou:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("sex, nov 6", "ddd, MMM d", new CultureInfo("pt-BR"))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KTVp8o). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ysDzA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/ParseExact2.cs).

Comment: Muito bom, funciona certinho.

Comment: Deu certinho obrigada